# Can I call a contract function in the "data" element via web3, especially when I am using conversion to bytes?

Tags: web3js, evm, web3.py, raw-transaction, bytes

In other words, say In Python I have something like that:

```
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(dict(
    nonce=w3.eth.getTransactionCount('0x0000000000000000000000000000000'),
    gasPrice = w3.eth.gasPrice, 
    gas = 100000,
    to='0x000000000000000000000000000000000',
    value=w3.toWei(0,'ether'),
data='a9059cbb000000000000000000000000583031d1113ad414f02576bd6afabfb302140225000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c'
  ),
  '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001')

w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

the "data" element above simply holds a sha3 conversion of the transfer function + its 2 arguments (send address and amount), as described by this chap here:

https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-data-payloads-in-ethereum-transactions-354dbe995371

I simply need a way to send the function call to contract via 'simple' way in bytes that I can get from Remix, instead of manually writing the call programically? Thanks!

Comment: I found this on chinese website, apparantly i am on the right track which leads to a new question - do i need to put '0x' in the beginning of data?     https://www.jianshu.com/p/496c9d833df9

Comment: Yes, because that is hex-encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

The `to` need to be the contract address.
And yes, data has to start with 0x.